# Write query to find unique users from a message table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a message table which stores conversations between 2 users. Structure of the table is as given below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message(
    message_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    from_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    to_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    message varchar(3000),
    mesaging_topic BIGINT(20),
    create_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(message_id)
);

ALTER TABLE message
   ADD CONSTRAINT message_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(from_id) REFERENCES user(id),
   ADD CONSTRAINT message_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(to_id) REFERENCES user(id),
   ADD CONSTRAINT message_fk3 FOREIGN KEY(messaging_topic) REFERENCES messaging_topic(messaging_topic_id);
```

I need to find a list of the first 10 conversations with a particular user in the descending order of create_date and the other user should not repeat in the result. The result should be like what we see in the Facebook messages.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @David I am not asking for simple query .. I am looking for only first conversation with different user and that too in the order of create_date .. Just like what we see in the facebook messages where we see only latest conversation with each user

Comment: @hiteshjain OP, do you want the last 10 messages a user has regardless of who they were with, or do you want the last 10 people? When you reference facebook message, do you mean like the little quick view where it shows the latest message in my 10 most recent conversations?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my incorrect assumption, I've decided to wipe my answer and give you a new one. This problem was really tricky.

I started from the barebones. I wrote a query to get all of the users someone has *sent* a message to, and a complement query to get all of the users someone has *received* a message from. I made a union to get all of the users someone has messaged with, in one way or another. That brought me here:

```
(SELECT from_id, MAX(create_date) AS latestMessage
FROM message
WHERE to_id = 1
GROUP BY from_id)
UNION
(SELECT to_id, MAX(create_date) AS latestMessage
FROM message
WHERE from_id = 1
GROUP BY to_id)
```

While I did that, I got the max date as the latest message for each pairing, grouping by the id.

However, this still isn't enough. It will pull the latest message from user 1->2 as well as the latest message from user 2->1. Now the above never includes user id 1, but just the users they've interacted with. So, I nested that into another query that took the max date of the groups above, to get say the latest message date from users 1 and 2 regardless of who sent it. That brought me here:

```
SELECT from_id, MAX(latestMessage) AS latestMessageBetweenUsers
FROM((SELECT from_id, MAX(create_date) AS latestMessage
   FROM message
   WHERE to_id = 1
   GROUP BY from_id)
   UNION
   (SELECT to_id, MAX(create_date) AS latestMessage
   FROM message
   WHERE from_id = 1
   GROUP BY to_id)) t
```

Now I have each user that user #1 has sent messages with, and the date of the last message. I then took that, and joined it with our original table on the condition that the id from above was equal to one of the ids in the original table, AND that the message date matched. I also had to filter again for user_id 1. I sorted by the descending message date, and uses the LIMIT clause to get the 10 most recent.

Here is the final query:

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
JOIN(SELECT from_id, MAX(latestMessage) AS latestMessageBetweenUsers
  FROM((SELECT from_id, MAX(create_date) AS latestMessage
     FROM message
     WHERE to_id = 1
     GROUP BY from_id)
     UNION
     (SELECT to_id, MAX(create_date) AS latestMessage
     FROM message
     WHERE from_id = 1
     GROUP BY to_id)) t
GROUP BY from_id) t
ON (t.from_id = m.from_id OR t.from_id = m.to_id) AND m.create_date = t.latestMessageBetweenUsers
WHERE m.from_id = 1 OR m.to_id = 1
ORDER BY t.latestMessageBetweenUsers DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

And here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1f0c/2). Of course I only used sample data, please verify in your database and get back to me.

Comment: This may give conversation between 2 users more than once. I need only latest conversation between 2 users in the result set.

Comment: @hiteshjain I have finally solved this. My class just began - I will notify you when I am able to edit my answer.

Comment: @hiteshjain please see my edit. That was an excellent problem, and very brain stimulating.

Answer (score -1):

suppose logged user is 20

```
SELECT `message_id`, IF(`from_id` = 20, `to_id`, `from_id`) AS `anotheruser`, 
IF(`from_id` = 20,`from_id`, `to_id`) AS `me`, `to_id`, `message`, `mesaging_topic`
FROM `message` 
WHERE (`from_id` = 20 OR `to_id` = 20) 
GROUP BY `anotheruser` ORDER BY `create_date` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: your solution is very close to what I am looking but I am getting the first conversation between 2 users. I want to get the latest conversation between 2 users.